# My "people reached" score went from 69K to 7K on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, people-reached

My "impact" on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4164585/siamak-ferdos?tab=profile) was 69K yesterday. But now instead of 70K, it is showing 7K. Is this a bug?

Comment: @rene I can't find anyone with a decimal point for those, so OP might have a point.

Comment: @rene Yes I am! I visit my page every day

Comment: @Shadow Wizard So you say(on duplicate one) that %80 of my question visitors are removed by Stack?! Is it reasonable? Why this happened on 69 and not 60 for example?!! The diffrence between 69K and 7K is 62K!

Comment: Most likely a popular question you answered, which had 62K views, has been deleted. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/4164585) - what do you see? (not a mod, so it's Page Not Found for me :))